# Analysis Proof for sequences belonging to closed intervals

Tags: real-analysis

A friend was recently asking me about a question they had in their course, where they were asked to prove that if a sequence $a_n$ has the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n$$=a$ and $a_n$ $\epsilon$ $I$ where $I$ is a closed interval $(b, c)$, then $a$ $\epsilon$ $I$. I made a pretty clumsy attempt at a proof, but Im pretty sure its wrong. Below is my attempt:

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n$$=a$ $\equiv$ $\forall e >0 \exists N \epsilon \Bbb N$:n $\ge$N $\Rightarrow$ $\lvert a_n - a \rvert$ $< e$

so $\forall n \ge N$

$-e<a_n - a <e$

$\Rightarrow$ $e>a - a_n >-e$

$\Rightarrow$ $a_n + e>a>a_n-e$

So we want to choose an $e$ such that:
$c \ge a_n+e$ and $b \ge a_n -e$

$\Rightarrow$ $c-a_n \ge e$ and $a_n -b \ge e$

so if we let $e = min (c-a_n, a_n -b)$ then we have $b<a<c$ so $a$ $\epsilon$ $I$

This doesn't seem right, however. Surely it would be possible to just come up with a sequence belonging to $I$ such that it converges to c, which would mean $b<a<c$ wouldn't make any sense and instead it would need to be $b \le a \le c$.

Also should I somehow justify why its possible to select and $e$ equal to $min (c-a_n, a_n -b)$?

If anyone could shed some light on where I went wrong and, if its all wrong, then if you could also please suggest a more appropriate approach to this question.

ps. Sorry if my formatting is a little rough, first time using MathJax.

Comment: Use `\in` to get "$\in$" and `\min` to get "$\min$", but your LaTeX is getting there!

Answer (score 0):

If $I$ is closed then any point $c$ outside of $I$ has a strictly positive distance to every point in $I$. This distance satisfies is $|a_n-c|\ge min(a-c,c-b)>0$. Hence $c$ cannot be the limit so $c$ is in $I$.

Regarding your work : In your proof, you use inequalities in both directions on some lines. This is wrong. Also the min may not exist but $inf$ will because it has to be bounded bellow by 0.

Comment: Yes, sorry that double inequality was a formatting typo, still getting used to the unusual way spaces seem to work. I think I understand my mistake now. Because $e>0$ and $min(c−a n ,a n −b)$ may both be negative numbers, right?